# Two facebook like buttons on same page with different count

Tags: facebook, button, count, facebook-like

I have two facebook like buttons on the same page, however they are showing two different counts.. I want them to show the same count.. 
I have an og:url meta tag set on the page, hence my assumption is that both the like buttons will share the same page url that is mentioned in the og:url.. But still they are showing different counts. Can someone please help me here.. 
The only difference is the href set in the two buttons is of a different format, however redirecting to the same page, so will this difference matter? 
Can someone please guide me what should be done to have both the like button counts same?

Comment: Are both url are exactly same in two like button api code?

Answer (score 1):

The hrefs set on the buttons themselves will override the og:url set. So even though the two slightly different links point to the same page, Facebook will see this as two pages.

Two solutions available:

1. Make both of the hrefs the same
2. Remove the hrefs and they will just refer to the current page they're on